# Grid of plots in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I need to display a grid of plots for a data frame which is 213 x 4.
When I use the following command in ggplot2, the plot is a long linear display of plots which are scrunched up

```
 ggplot(data=r,aes(x=wicketPlayerOut,y=runs,fill=wicketPlayerOut)) + 
    facet_grid(. ~ bowler,scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

I tried to use facet_wrap but I get an error

"Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting"

The command I used for facet_wrap is as follows

```
   ggplot(data=r,aes(x=wicketPlayerOut,y=runs,fill=wicketPlayerOut)) + 
    facet_wrap(. ~ bowler,scales = "fixed",ncol=4,drop=TRUE)+
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

How can I display as A x B rows by columns of plots?
[image]

Comment: Change the formula in `facet_wrap` to `~ bowler`.

Comment: Roland - Thx. I just did and it worked.You could answer the question and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed to the following

```
ggplot(data=r,aes(x=wicketPlayerOut,y=runs,fill=wicketPlayerOut)) + 
facet_wrap( ~ bowler,scales = "fixed",ncol=4,drop=TRUE)+
geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

and the display is now as nrow x ncol